# Closing page animation on browser refresh / clicking the internal menu links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

I made a opening page animation, it runs soon as page is loaded.

My problem is closing animation timing. It lasts 2 sec for example and I liked to implement it on browser refresh/clicking the internal menu links (browser actions the most).
I know how to run the script on onunload and looked into a lot of implementations but problem is browser  leaves the page before those 2 sec are over. It cuts the animation that i see has started.

Is it possible to make the browser halt the refresh or loading next page for 2 sec?

Only thing I could think of if is the bound JS code on my internal links to start the closing animation and after 2 sec make the actual link redirect. Lats say that would work in internal links but can i make a browser actions do the same?

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#plahta').prop('checked', false);
  });
}, 2000);


setTimeout(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#plahta').prop('checked', true);
  });
}, 4000);
```

```css
.curtain {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.curtain__wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.curtain__wrapper input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.curtain__wrapper input[type=checkbox]:checked~div.curtain__panel--left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.curtain__wrapper input[type=checkbox]:checked~div.curtain__panel--right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.curtain__panel {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #23232e;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 80;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.curtain__panel--left {
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.curtain__panel--right {
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.curtain__content {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="curtain">
  <div class="curtain__wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="plahta" checked>
    <div class="curtain__panel curtain__panel--left">
      <span class="intro">DOBRO</span>
    </div>
    <main class="wrapper dark curtain__content" id="main">
      <div id="fullpage" class="w3-container spinner">
        <h1>TEST</h1>
      </div>
    </main>
    <div class="curtain__panel curtain__panel--right">
      <span class="intro">DOŠLI</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You really need to use a Single Page architecture for anything like this to work

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I understand what are you saying,I am already  using full page sections but there are just a couple of sub pages that should be by them self, different designs and all, so i thought too separate them. It is light weight  and fast now, so separating them sounded like better thing to do then load all on one go, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pause, stop or prevent the browser from exiting or refreshing a page apart from using `alert()`.

If you want to, say redirect, you can detect the `click` event on an element, trigger the animation, and set a callback on animation finish to `location.href = "someurl"` with the URL you want to redirect to.

I think you could manage to handle the refresh in a single-page web app. But it doesn't mean you should. When people exit / refresh, they won't care to see an animation play out. That's my UX advice.

Comment: Yeah I know about alert, that's why I rather asked is there any other workaround maybe. As far as click goes i mentioned that myself in "Only thing I could think of " part. And I think ill do that.  And as I don't think ill get any other answer to this (had to ask), ill accept yours later so you get your first points. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks. Imagine if it was possible to stop a page from closing with JS - and you couldn't close some ad pop-ups, or worse, porn pop-ups?

Comment: Oh I know all that, not my first rodeo. Question was not about closing, it was about halting/prolonging/delaying  refreshing and opening internal domain links. But looks like I let my imagination running a bit to wild with this one. Cheers.